# RecyclerView lags for the first (4 - 5) scrolls

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have created my own CalendarYearView list using RecyclerView for my project. It lags for the first few scrolls (4 - 5 scrolls), but after that it's been faster.I couldn't find out what's the problem.

I tried adding `setHasFixedSize(true)` and `setHasStableIds(true)`. But both these cases not working.

It's happening in all the devices, i tried **Samsung S8**, **moto G3** and **Xiomi MI Pad**

I've attached my files below, Give me some suggestions to resolve this probem.

**YearListActivity**

```
class YearsListActivity : BaseActivity(), SimpleYearCallback {
private var currYear: Int = 0
private var currPos: Int = 0
var l: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
private var mAdapter: YearsRecyclerAdapter? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_years_list)
    init()
}

override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setTitle(getString(R.string.tit_choose_year), false)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    refresh()
}

override fun init() {
    mAdapter = YearsRecyclerAdapter(this, l)
    mAdapter?.callback = this
    val llm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    llm.orientation = RecyclerView.VERTICAL
    recycler?.layoutManager = llm
    val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler)
    recycler?.adapter = mAdapter
}

override fun refresh() {
    l.clear()
    for (i in GAuth.getInstance().minYear..GAuth.getInstance().maxYear) {
        l.add(i)
    }
    currYear = CalendarUtil.calendar().get(Calendar.YEAR)
    currPos = currYear - GAuth.getInstance().minYear
    recycler?.scrollToPosition(currPos)
    mAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onMonthClicked(month: Int, year: Int) {
    ActivityManager.goHomeActivity(this, CalendarUtil.calendar(year, month).timeInMillis)
}
}
```

**YearRecyclerAdapter**

```
class YearsRecyclerAdapter(private var mContext: Context,
                       private var l: List<Int>)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<YearsRecyclerAdapter.SimpleYearHolder>() {

var callback: SimpleYearCallback? = null

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return l.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)
        : SimpleYearHolder {
    return SimpleYearHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.view_simple_year_view_static,
                    parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimpleYearHolder
                              , position: Int) {
    val year = l[position]
    holder.itemView.title.text = year.toString()
    for (i in 0 until CalendarData.MONTHS) {
        holder.initSMV(holder.itemView.
                findViewById(ResourceUtil.getId(mContext,
                "month$i", ResourceUtil.RES_ID)),
                year, 0)
    }
}

inner class SimpleYearHolder(itemView: View)
    : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var year: Int = 0

    fun initSMV(smv: SimpleMonthView, year: Int, month: Int) {
        smv.millis = CalendarUtil.calendar(year, month).timeInMillis
        smv.setOnClickListener {
            callback?.onMonthClicked(month, year)
        }
        smv.refresh()
    }
}
}
```

**SimpleMonthView**

```
class SimpleMonthView : LinearLayout, ViewInitializer {
var millis: Long = 0
var l: ArrayList<String>? = ArrayList()
var cal: Calendar? = null
var title: CustomTextView? = null
private var isCurrentMonth = false
private var todayDate: Int? = -1

constructor(context: Context)
        : super(context) {
    initView()
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?)
        : super(context, attrs) {
    initView()
}

override fun initAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet?) {

}

override fun initView() {
    View.inflate(context,
            R.layout.view_simple_month_view_static,
            this)
    title = findViewById(R.id.title)
}

override fun refresh() {
    title?.text =
            CalendarUtil.getMonthName(CalendarUtil.calendar(millis))
    generateGrid()
}

override fun destroy() {

}

private fun generateGrid() {
    cal = CalendarUtil.calendar(millis)
    if (CalendarUtil.isSameMonth(millis,
                    CalendarUtil.calendar().timeInMillis)) {
        isCurrentMonth = true
        todayDate = CalendarUtil.calendar()
                .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    }
    var count = CalendarData.WEEK
    if (CalendarUtil.getMonthStartPos(cal)!! !=
            Calendar.SUNDAY)
        for (i in 1 until CalendarUtil.getMonthStartPos(cal)!!) {
            count++
        }
    for (i in 1..CalendarUtil.getMonthMaxDays(cal)!!) {
        val tv = findViewById<SquareTextView>
```

(ResourceUtil.getId(context,
                    "day$count",
                    ResourceUtil.RES_ID))
            tv.text = i.toString()
            tv.setTextColor(
                    if (isCurrentMonth && i == todayDate) 
                        Color.RED
                    else 
                        ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                                R.color.default_txt_color)
            )
            count++
        }
    }

```
}
```

**layout/activity_years_list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_container"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout/adapter_simple_year_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/space_4dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_4dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_thin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/year_header"
    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_large"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month0"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month1"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month2"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month3"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month4"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month5"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month6"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month7"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month8"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month9"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month10"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

        <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.calendar.SimpleMonthView
            android:id="@+id/month11"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/space_4dp"
            style="@style/SimpleMonthView.EqWidth" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/view_simple_month_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

<chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/space_4dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_tiny" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day0"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="S" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="M" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day2"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="T" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day3"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="W" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day4"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="T" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day5"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="F" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day6"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin"
        android:text="S" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day7"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day8"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day9"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day10"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day11"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day12"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day13"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day14"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day15"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day16"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day17"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day18"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day19"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day20"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day21"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day22"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day23"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day24"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day25"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day26"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day27"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day28"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day29"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day30"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day31"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day32"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day33"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day34"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day35"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day36"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day37"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day38"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day39"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day40"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day41"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day42"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day43"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day44"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day45"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day46"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day47"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />

    <chuchu.guruji.scheduler.view.SquareTextView
        android:id="@+id/day48"
        style="@style/CustomTextView.Thin" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="CustomTextView.Thin">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/txt_tiny</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_txt_color</item>
</style>
```

My final Year list view

[image]

Comment: You may want to tell on which device you're experiencing this issues (processor, RAM, OS version). Does this happen in more than one device?
Have you already run UI performance tests? If so, what tools have you used?

Comment: Its happening in all the devices, i tried Samsung S8, moto G3 and Xiomi MI Pad

Comment: IMO, the lag happen because your looping in `onBindViewHolder`. As far I know, that method is not for handle many high activity/process. Maybe you can try to move handle your data process to other function. Use set and get for simple try

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta onBindViewHolder binds 12 month data. I emptied onBindViewHolder and ran the code, still it was slow for the first 4-5 item scrolls